# CLCircularRegion didEnterRegion not working

Tags: ios, swift, geofencing, clcircularregion

I have a GPX that simulates the movement to the coordinate. I can't get CLCircularRegion to fire for nothing. I've tried to put the code everywhere. Here's what I'm using:

```
var center: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.33171100, -122.03018400)
var radius: CLLocationDistance = CLLocationDistance(300)
var identifier: String = "Destination"
let region = CLCircularRegion(center: center, radius: radius, identifier: identifier)
manager!.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
```

I've placed this everywhere. I've put this in:

```
viewDidLoad 
viewWillAppear
viewDidAppear
mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(mapView: MKMapView!
mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap(mapView: MKMapView!, fullyRendered: Bool)
locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
```

Here is my GPX file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <gpx version="1.1" creator="Xcode">
      <wpt lat="37.331711" lon="-122.030184">
               <name>Apple</name>
      </wpt>
      <wpt lat="37.422455" lon="-122.084306">
              <name>Google</name>
      </wpt>
</gpx>
```

`Println` works in `didStartMonitoringRegion` and it prints the region's info to the logs but it doesn't fire. Nothing seems to work and its driving me insane. Here is my full program.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

var mapView: MKMapView?
var manager: CLLocationManager?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView = MKMapView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height))
    self.mapView!.delegate = self
    mapView!.showsUserLocation = true
    view.addSubview(mapView!)   
   }

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion!) {
    println("Entered")
   }

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didStartMonitoringForRegion region: CLRegion!) {
    println("Monitoring")
    println(region)
}

func mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(mapView: MKMapView!) {
    manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager!.delegate = self
    manager!.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager!.startUpdatingLocation()

    var center: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.33171100, -122.03018400)
    var radius: CLLocationDistance = CLLocationDistance(300)
    var identifier: String = "Destination"
    let region = CLCircularRegion(center: center, radius: radius, identifier: identifier)
    manager!.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have got to be kidding me. Its because I used `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` instead of `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in the `info.plist`